# AS3 Error: 1078: Label must be a simple identifier

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some code not written by me that I'm trying to compile.

```js
public static function getUserInfoObject(info:Array) : Object {
     var lastBattleTime:Number = info[7];
     var listLength:Number = info[8];
     var list:Array = info.slice(9,9 + listLength);
     var achievesLength:Number = info[9 + listLength];
     var achievements:Array = info.slice(10 + listLength,10 + listLength + achievesLength);
     var statsLength:Number = info[10 + listLength + achievesLength];
     var stats:Array = info.slice(11 + listLength + achievesLength,11 + listLength + achievesLength + statsLength);
     var commonInfo:Array = info.slice(11 + listLength + achievesLength + statsLength,11 + listLength + achievesLength + statsLength + 8);
     return 
        {
           "uid":info[0],
           "name":info[1],
           "chatRoster":info[2],
           "status":info[3],
           "displayName":info[5],
           "list":list,
           "achievements":achievements,
           "stats":stats,
           "commonInfo":commonInfo,
           "creationTime":App.utils.locale.longDate(info[6]),
           "lastBattleTime":(lastBattleTime == 0?"":App.utils.locale.longDate(lastBattleTime) + " " + App.utils.locale.longTime(lastBattleTime))
        };
  }
```

It gives me this error: `1078: Label must be a simple identifier.` in every line in return.

Am I blind or dumb or this code is bad?

Comment: try removing all the quotation marks "" in the return statement.

Comment: @DodgerThud No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start your return statement with the curly brace, not with new line:

```
public static function getUserInfoObject(info:Array) : Object {
    return {  // <-Here
    };
}
```